# Xamarin without Forms/MvvmCross/Data binding

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on defining an architecture to write Android/iOS apps with shared code in Xamarin without Forms.

It seems like MVVM is the most popular architecture. I looked at MvvmCross example and while I can see the benefit of how much code is sharable, I didn't like how the native-ness fades out from the Android/iOS projects.

Is data binding essential in implementing Xamarin with MVVM? Are there examples of Xamarin MVVM without MvvmCross and data binding?

Comment: "I didn't like how the native-ness fades out from the Android/iOS projects" what do you mean?

Comment: With MvvmCross, you don't write code like it's a Android or iOS wrapper API. MvvmCross brings a very different way of coding with its framework.

Answer (score 0):

When I first started using Xamarin I followed this example project as a guide:
https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/MWC

It doesn't use data binding, nor does it use ViewModels. However, you could easily move away from using their static "Manager" classes to ViewModels or any architecture really.

Their Tasky sample app uses a Manager/Repository architecture:
https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/TaskyPortable

Before I moved to using MVVMCross in my projects, I created a framework called MonkeyArms that uses a Mediator paradigm that you may find interesting:
https://github.com/benbishop/MonkeyArms